# In Corda, can I create additional tables in my node's database to store information?

Tags: corda

Corda nodes automatically generate their own set of database tables to store information.

Is it ok for me to create my own additional tables in this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create additional tables in your node's database. This will not cause problems for your node.